# How do I fully disable chat in Quake Live?

Tags: quake-live

I've disabled global chat with cg_teamchatsonly 1 and voice chat with some command I found in the internet (don't remember), but obviously couldn't disable teamchat. How do I fully disable chat in QL? Can't play 1 game in peace with all those bullies.